# Output the nearest Value of an List which match to an String?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, chess

I am scraping a Chess Game. I want to get a Suggested move.

```
best_move_dataset = Collection of played Moves in the History
move_done = is the move i have played if the app started

Solution-Output (best_move_dataset == move_done): nearest equality
f6
f5
```

This is my code and I really dont know how to make this solution.

```
best_move_dataset = ['d4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4 f6','d4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4 f5','d4 Nc6 e3 e5 f4']

moves_done = 'd4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4'
moves_done_list = moves_done.split(' ')
len_moves_done = len(moves_done_list)

len_best_move = len(best_move_dataset)

for move_zaehler in range(len_moves_done):
        print(best_move_dataset[0])
```

I hope you guys understand If you have any Suggestion how I can change the Question that it is clearer then please remind me.

Hopefully I get some Help.

Best Regards

Tobias

Comment: I think that you should invest in Tries.  If you create a Trie with a bunch of lists of move orders, you can then walk it and get a given move at ANY point in time.  Its pretty legit.

Comment: does order matter? I mean `move_done` should always be substring o f any element of `best_move_dataset`

Answer (score 0):

```
best_move_dataset = ['d4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4 f6','d4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4 f5','d4 Nc6 e3 e5 f4']
moves_done = 'd4 Nc6 e4 e5 f4'

best_sequences = [str_.split() for str_ in best_move_dataset]
moves_sequence = moves_done.split()
count = len(moves_sequence)
suggestions = []

for best_sequence in best_sequences:
    if len(best_sequence) > count:
        if moves_sequence == best_sequence[:count]:
            suggestions.append(best_sequence[count])

for suggestion in suggestions:
    print(suggestion)
```

Output:

> ```
> f6
> f5
> ```

---

*The explanation:*

After splitting strings of move sequences into lists, we compare the sequence of the *done* moves to *every* move sequence *in the history* (in the `for` loop).

If that sequence is *longer* than the sequence of the done moves, and its *shortened part* is *the same* as the sequence of the done moves, we add the next move of that sequence to the prepared list of suggestions.

Then in the `for` loop we print them.

---

*Note:*

Instead of the used list comprehension you may write:

```
best_sequences = []
for str_ in best_move_dataset:
    best_sequences.append(str_.split())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I must dive more into List Comprehension

Comment: You're welcome. I added a substitution for the used list comprehension into my answer. Please vote up and/or accept my answer if it was useful for you.